# Google Trends Category Search

Tags: python, categories, google-trends

I'm trying to **extract/download Google Trends Series Data by category and/or subcategory** with Python based on this list in the following link: https://github.com/pat310/google-trends-api/wiki/Google-Trends-Categories

This list of categories contains codes that are used in the (unofficial) API of Google Trends, named **pytrends**.
However, I'm not able to search only by category because it is required to give a **keyword/search term.** In the case below, we have category 47 (Autos & Vehicles) and keywords ['BMW', 'Peugeot'].

```
import pytrends
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrend = TrendReq()


pytrend = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)
keywords = ['BMW', 'Peugeot']
pytrend.build_payload(
     kw_list=keywords,
     cat=47,
     timeframe='today 3-m',
     geo='FR',
     gprop='')
data = pytrend.interest_over_time()
data= data.drop(labels=['isPartial'],axis='columns')
image = data.plot(title = 'BMW V.S. Peugeot in last 3 months on Google Trends ')
fig = image.get_figure()
```

I found this as a possible solution, but I haven't tried because it's in R:
https://github.com/PMassicotte/gtrendsR/issues/89

I don't know if there is an API that would give this possibility to extract series by category and ignoring keyword/search term. Let me know if it exists. I believe an option would be to download directly from Google Trends website and filling up just the category field, like this example where we can see the series for category "Autos & Vehicles":
https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?cat=47&date=all&geo=SG

Comment: You can try this service from Rapid API rapidapi.com/anju.313/api/google-trends, But be mindful this is a paid service. But they have good interfacing guide lines.

Answer (score 2):

You may search via category with empty string in the kw_list array:

```
keywords = ['']

pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=[''], cat=47,
                           timeframe='today 3-m', geo='FR', gprop='')
data = pytrend.interest_over_time()
```